# Unable to change URL path after updating attributes with friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I've been following the Railscast tutorial on how to implement friendly_id and for some reason my URL's doesn't change after I update my attributes.

Say I registered a user with :fullname 'John Doe' it creates the slug /john-doe successfully. However if I update my name to 'Test user' the url is still /john-doe

My current setup is this:

**users_controller**

```
def show
 @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

**model - user.rb**

```
extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :fullname, use: [:slugged, :history]
```

I've also migrated

```
class AddSlugsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  add_column :users, :slug, :string
  add_index :users, :slug, unique: true
 end
end
```

so that is working. Also installed

```
rails generate friendly_id
```

and done:

```
User.find_each(&:save)
```

in rails c

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**friendly_id**

It's a common issue with friendly_id - [it defaults to setting the `slug` only if the `slug` attribute is blank](http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/Slugged):

---

**Documentation**

> As of FriendlyId 5.0, slugs are only generated when the slug field is
>   nil. If you want a slug to be regenerated,set the slug field to nil:

```
restaurant.friendly_id # joes-diner
restaurant.name = "The Plaza Diner"
restaurant.save!
restaurant.friendly_id # joes-diner
restaurant.slug = nil
restaurant.save!
restaurant.friendly_id # the-plaza-diner
```

You can also override the #should_generate_new_friendly_id? method, which lets you control exactly when new friendly ids are set:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, :use => :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    title_changed?
  end
end
```

If you want to extend the default behavior but, adding your own conditions, don't forget to invoke super from your implementation:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    name_changed? || super
  end
end
```

---

For you, I'd recommend:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...

   def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      name_changed? || super
   end
end
```

Comment: that worked. However I want to do a 301 redirect on old urls and I tried adding 
def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if request.path != user_path(@user)
      redirect_to @user, status: :moved_permanently
    end
  end
but got undefined method `user_path'. The show file (profile page) is stored inside 'users/show.html.erb' so why isn't that path working? My routes are setup like this:  get '/intern/:id', to: 'users#show'

Comment: You'll need to include the [`history`](http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/History) option in `friendly_id` - this will create a table called `friendly_id_slugs`, which will store historic data (which will redirect automatically)

Comment: I did:     friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :history]

  # Try building a slug based on the following fields in
  # increasing order of specificity.
  def slug_candidates
    [
      :fullname,
      [:fullname, :id]
    ]
  end 

and I have generated the friendly_id table 
but I want it to redirect the URL so if I go to /rich-1 and change it to rich-2 and visit rich-2 it needs to redirect you to rich-2. If that makes sense?

Comment: Did you try restarting your Rails server/

Comment: Figured out the problem. It was my routing.

Comment: Hell yes :) now I can visit rich-1 and it redirects me to rich-2 (the current url) and everything else working fine as-well. Due to your def ....  name_changed? || super end 

Only problem now is my slug_candidates. Trying to add :fullname, Random.new.rand(1..100) so I avoid the ugly UUID . However not working.

Comment: It's another feature of `friendly_id` I think - there is a way to change it, but I can't remember unfortunately ^_^. Glad it helped though!

Comment: got it working now with:   friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :history]

  def slug_candidates
    [
      :fullname,
      [:fullname, Random.new.rand(1..100)]
    ]
  end